# Prove that $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{n^2} n\sin (x/n)e^{-x^2} dx = 1/2 $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> Prove that
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{n^2} n\sin(x/n)e^{-x^2} dx = 1/2.$$

I've tried all of the techniques learned in the course so far and none of them seem to work, so if anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand intuitively why it is true/how to practically get the answer? Can you name some of the techniques of your course, that you have tried?

Comment: You can take the limit under the integral and take the upper bound of the integral as $\infty$ right away, then you get an elementary integral returning the correct value

Comment: @stijn We've learned how to solve problems like this with integration by parts, using the power series, and differentiating under the integral sign. We haven't covered an example where the thing we're taking the limit of is in the limit of the integral though.

Comment: @Ellie_P so some people below answered in some detail already, and more properly than I will. I was asking for clarification partly because it is good practice to give a bit of background (on what you've tried) and partly because the level of rigor expected when "proving" something differs a lot between courses. Your case sounds not too formal. The main point is $\sin(y) \sim y$ as $y\rightarrow0$, so $n \sin{x/n} \rightarrow x$. You might worry whether this is ok to do inside the integral (it is here, see answers), once you do this the integral becomes something simple to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You may need to show:

\begin{align} 
|\sin(x/n) |\leq \frac{|x|} {n} 
\end{align} 
So now one has
\begin{align} 
0\leq n|\sin(x/n) |e^{-x^2}\leq |x|e^{-x^2}
\end{align} 
Your integral is:
\begin{align} 
\int^\infty_0 \mathbf{1}_{(0,n^2)}n\sin(x/n)e^{-x^2}\,dx
\end{align} 
Now apply The Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude.